# Hiding secret key in server OR externalizing application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, environment-variables

I have some secret api keys for my server and i have to use in my project. But i am not feeling safe to keep in properties file or any physical location in server. Can any one tell me what are possible ways to keep it secret and use  wherever it's require in application.

Comment: What's the file mode (`chmod`) of your property file?

Comment: read only @rookie099

Comment: So that's already good and also what you will find in many setups. The other measure that I can think of is making sure that you use an API key whose capabilities are very narrowly defined (just gives access to one particular, needed API, or similar). So in case it is compromised you don't loole (too) much.

Comment: Assuming you can't afford an HSM. Place the password in a file on your server that's readable only by the userid that runs your REST server. And don't share that userid with anything else. If someone can get root access to your server and read your password file then it's game over anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really considered about the passwords you've got, the best way is using HSM (Hardware security module). This way you will be assured that keeping your private key in a secure place is not part of your consideration anymore.

If that is expensive, then you can think of storing your private key in JKS or PKCS12 and choose a strong password.

Generally you are looking for a vault. In PKI you can have a vault to store your secret in it. there are couple of ways I can think of. One of them is HSM as I described above and the other one is following:

For storing your password you need to salt it or store it in another server w/ salt and whenever you need the password, it's better to have a secure connection between your real server and password only stored server to request the password.

Also you can take a look at this project from Hashicorp
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault

Answer (score 0):

There are many options here depending on your actual security requirements.
You've mentioned java and spring boot, so I'll mainly specify solutions related to this technology stack.

Since you're already using Spring Boot, consider spring-cloud-config server.

It has some interesting "encryption" features:

**Step 1**

Create a Key (public/private pair or shared depending on your requirements)
Specify it when starting the config server (via -- or env variable):

```
encrypt.key=ABC123ABC123ABC123
```

**Step 2**

Encode value of the password by calling a rest request of this server (you do it once)

```
curl localhost:8888/encrypt -d mysecretdbpassword 
>>AZXCASDAZXC341234ZXCASDFedr453
```

**Step 3**

In application.properties specify that the value is "encrypted" with a special syntax
The file will be stored on a configuration server and not on the microservice. The 
property will look like this

```
db.password={cipher}AZXCASDAZXC341234ZXCASDFedr453
```

The property will be kept encrypted in files but decrypted in memory. So the microservice will get a decrypted value.

The documentation is available [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/). This is by far the fastest way to implement the requirements. You can keep it in a dedicated microservice or embedded into the already-existing application.

In addition, it allows integration with JKS, so its possible to store passwords there.

**Complementary/Alternatives**

Spring cloud config is also integrated with [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault-announcement) which can be a good solution for your situation on its own (even without spring boot cloud config).

Yet Another possible solution that comes from Spring Universe is called [Spring Vault](https://projects.spring.io/spring-vault/)
Its intended for working with secrets.

Comment: Not me downvoting but... the config server stores its keys where exactly?

Comment: On a different machine, so if you have, say 100 microservices that need some protected property (db password, aws key, whatever) they can call the config server and get the decrypted data (of course the channel should be protected, but its inside the network over http or https if required), so these 100 machines store the information only in memory. Now as for the config server itself it depends, there are many options. Its possible to create keys in a secret place and supply it in runtime (in the example, the env. variable is defined / argument to program start), but there are many options..

Answer (score 0):

I use [onboardbase](https://onboardbase.com) to hide secret i would recommend that they are few other out there to check like doppler

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your application.properties as below

`application.properties`

---

```
secret.key1=${SECRET_KEY1}
secret.key2=${SECRET_KEY2}
```

While building the application we can pass it as an environment variable

> mvn clean install -dSECRET_KEY1=123456 -dSECRET_KEY2=abcdef

We can pass the environment variables in docker as well by using -e SECRET_KEY1=123456